# Advice on an expression to trim text

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm having some data coming through in an SSRS report as:

Mr John Smith (12, Livia Close, Anytown, 125765)

Can anyone advise on how I can remove the 'Mr John Smith' part and also the brackets around the address? I would like to just have:

12, Livia Close, Anytown, 125765

Any advice appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your field is called `Address` use the following expression:

```
=Mid(Fields!Address.Value, InStr(Fields!Address.Value, "(") + 1, InStr(Fields!Address.Value, ")") - InStr(Fields!Address.Value, "(") - 1)
```